FlatList becomes unresponsive while fetching more data
I am trying to create an infinite scroll using FlatList. However, I noticed that while fetching more data to the FlatList when reaching the end, the app gets unresponsive and I can't press anywhere until the data is fetched.
While fetching the data, the console.log won't appear because the pressing event is unresponsive.
This is the code:

import { FlatList, Text } from "react-native";
import * as S from "./styles";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { searchUsers } from "src/services/users/graphql/query";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { getImagePathFromObj } from "@helpers/getImagePath";

export const Playground = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const { loading, error, fetchMore } = useQuery(searchUsers, {
        variables: {
            name: "",
            latestLatitude: 64.71998823308158,
            latestLongitude: 175.5945099215997,
            page: 1,
        },
        onCompleted: (data) => {
            setUsers(data?.searchUsers || []);
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.error("Error fetching users:", error);
        },
    });

    const handleLoadMore = async () => {
        fetchMore({
            variables: {
                name: "",
                latestLatitude: 64.71998823308158,
                latestLongitude: 175.5945099215997,
                page: 1,
            },
            updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
                setUsers((prev) => [...prev, ...fetchMoreResult?.searchUsers]);
            },
        });
    };

    const RenderItem = React.memo(({ item }) => {
        console.log("item", item);

        return (
            <S.Profile onPress={() => console.log("press")}>
                <S.ProfileImage source={{ uri: getImagePathFromObj(item) }} />
            </S.Profile>
        );
    });

    const renderItem = (props) => <RenderItem {...props} />;

    const keyExtractor = (item) => item.id.toString();

    return (
        <S.Container>
            {loading && <Text>Loading...</Text>}
            {error && <Text>Error loading users</Text>}
            <FlatList
                data={users}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                numColumns={2}
                onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
                onEndReachedThreshold={1}
                initialNumToRender={1}
            />
        </S.Container>
    );
};

I tried memoizing the renderItem component too, but it didn't work.
I guess the problem happens whenever the user state gets updated.
I don't know if the desired behavior can be achieved with FlatList, but I appreciate any help!

Try FlashList instead

Instead of setting state directly in the updateQuery function, you should modify the data in the fetchMore call. You can leverage the updateQuery function to append the new data to the existing list.
const handleLoadMore = async () => {
        if (loading) return; // Prevent multiple requests

        await fetchMore({
            variables: {
                name: "",
                latestLatitude: 64.71998823308158,
                latestLongitude: 175.5945099215997,
                page: Math.floor(users.length / PAGE_SIZE) + 1,
            },
            updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
                if (!fetchMoreResult) return previousResult;
                return {
                    ...previousResult,
                    searchUsers: [
                        ...previousResult.searchUsers,
                        ...fetchMoreResult.searchUsers,
                    ],
                };
            },
        });
    };

also change

onEndReachedThreshold = 0.5

